# Angular2 deletes invalid inputs for <input type="number">?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

See this plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nGKAnXrrzgKSxpkdvEhX?p=preview

I have a simple `<form>` in Angular that displays a `<input type="number">` field.

When I enter something like "123" everything is ok.

But the input "123-456" seems to be ok, too, although this is not a "real" number. I found out that Angular sets the `myNumber.value` to `null` and so everything seems to be ok.

What I want to achieve is that Angular doesn't reset the input `"123-456"` to `null` and instead tells me that the input is invalid.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Try to set a FormControlGroup on your form and then set a FormControlName on the input that will show the error in case the inserted input is invalid.  
Let me know in case you don't know how to use FormControls in angular.

Comment: I think I already used [formGroup] and [formControlName] directives. <form [formGroup]="myForm"> <input type="number" formControlName="myNumber"> </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `type="number"` add a simple function that allows only numbers and `-` key.

`<input  formControlName="myNumber" #myNumber (keydown)=onlyNumberKey($event)><br>`

```
onlyNumberKey(event){
        let charCode = (event.query) ? event.query : event.keyCode;
        console.log(charCode);
            if (charCode != 189 && charCode > 31
                && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            return true;
    }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j9fk99j9Kyq0LkrxHqPJ?p=preview)